# Check if value exists in JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am learning NodeJS . I am using a JSON Object to check if a user is present.

This is my JSON (users.json):

```
{
    "users": [{
        "fname": "Robert",
        "lname": "Downey Jr.",
        "password": "ironman"
    }, {
        "fname": "Chris",
        "lname": "Evans",
        "password": "cap"
    }, {
        "fname": "Chris",
        "lname": "Hemsworth",
        "password": "thor"
    }, {
        "fname": "Jeremy",
        "lname": "Renner",
        "password": "hawk"
    }]
}
```

Now I want to pass the fname value of one entry and see if it exists in the JSON Object.

This is what I'm doing :

```
var file = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('users.json', 'utf8'));
for (eachUser in file.users) {
            console.log(eachUser.fname);
        }
```

But I do not get the fname values but just `undefined` . I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Also is there a way to find if the value exists without having to iterate over the JSON Object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `eachUser` gets set to each index in the array - not the object at that index. If you log just `eachUser`, you'll see

```
0
1
2
3
```

Instead, pull out the object first, and then gets its `fname`

```
for (index in file.users) {
  console.log(file.users[index].fname)
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/k9obv0ac/).

If you want to do this lookup without iterating through the array, you can re-shape your data into an object with `fname` as the key, so it would look like:

```
{
  "Robert": {
    "fname": "Robert",
    "lname": "Downey Jr.",
    "password": "ironman"
  },
  "Chris": {
    "fname": "Chris",
    "lname": "Evans",
    "password": "cap"
  },
  "Jeremy": {
    "fname": "Jeremy",
    "lname": "Renner",
    "password": "hawk"
  }
}
```

Of course, then either you won't be able to store any duplicate first names, or your need to make the values arrays.

Comment: Yup ! this works. But can this be done without the loop. Just asking to see if there are any other ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( typeof file !== 'undefined' && file )
{
   //do stuff if file is defined and not null
}
```

Comment: Or shorter: `if (file != null)`.

Comment: I want to check if the value such as 'Chris' , 'Robert' , exists in the JSON Object. Not to check if file is null or not..

Comment: Before those can exist, the file must exist. Then you can nest into it.

Answer (score -1):

You have an issue in your iteration statement:

```
for (eachUser in file.users)
```

Feel free to use one the `foreach` statements described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript) such as:

```
file.users.forEach(function(user) {
    console.log(user.fname);
});
```

Cheers

Comment: can u reframe your answer ? I do not get where this applies in here.